# Visual Composer to HTML

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, visual-composer

I am using woocommerce for one of my proyects, I am getting the description of the item but I am getting this in the format of visual composer, backery, js_composer or whatever name you Identify, my question is how to translate visual composer to HTML from wordpress or woocommerce? any way is acceptable I need to present this to my client tomorrow. thank you very much for your help!

The description output:

[vc_row content_placement="middle" css=".vc_custom_1460727920666{padding-top: 0px !important;padding-bottom: 0px !important;background-color: #f2f2f2 !important;}"][vc_column css=".vc_custom_1460636569719{padding: 20% !important;}" offset="vc_col-lg-6 vc_col-md-6"][title_subtitle add_subtitle="use_subtitle" title="Tasting notes" subtitle="Wine specs"][vc_column_text css=".vc_custom_1493324745269{margin-bottom: 0px !important;}"]Tequila suave que resalta los sabores más puros del agave, notas suaves y florales obtenidas por un reposo de casi seis meses en contenedores especiales.[/vc_column_text][/vc_column][vc_column css=".vc_custom_1460635864072{padding-top: 0px !important;padding-right: 0px !important;padding-bottom: 0px !important;padding-left: 0px !important;}" offset="vc_col-lg-6 vc_col-md-6 vc_hidden-sm vc_hidden-xs"][vc_single_image image="1088" img_size="full" css=".vc_custom_1469109337733{margin-bottom: 0px !important;}"][/vc_column][/vc_row][vc_row content_placement="middle" css=".vc_custom_1460727927848{padding-top: 0px !important;padding-bottom: 0px !important;background-color: #f2f2f2 !important;}"][vc_column css=".vc_custom_1460635871252{padding-top: 0px !important;padding-right: 0px !important;padding-bottom: 0px !important;padding-left: 0px !important;}" offset="vc_col-lg-6 vc_col-md-6 vc_hidden-sm vc_hidden-xs"][vc_single_image image="1089" img_size="full" css=".vc_custom_1469109351319{margin-bottom: 0px !important;}"][/vc_column][vc_column css=".vc_custom_1460636579755{padding: 20% !important;}" offset="vc_col-lg-6 vc_col-md-6"][title_subtitle add_subtitle="use_subtitle" title="Food pairing notes" subtitle="Wine specs"][vc_column_text]One of our favorite blocks from the Villenoir vineyard. This block tends to lift the aromatic character and soften the palate of our Cabernet Sauvignon. We are proud to offer this very limited and barrel selected wine as a stand alone block.[/vc_column_text][/vc_column][/vc_row][vc_row content_placement="middle" css=".vc_custom_1460727935440{padding-top: 0px !important;padding-bottom: 0px !important;background-color: #f2f2f2 !important;}"][vc_column css=".vc_custom_1460636587092{padding: 20% !important;}" offset="vc_col-lg-6 vc_col-md-6"][title_subtitle add_subtitle="use_subtitle" title="Winemaker notes" subtitle="Wine specs"][vc_column_text]Deep garnet with a vibrant ruby edge, velvety soft on the palate with bright cherry to plum flavors. This wine is weighty and full of fresh ripe berries with rich, dark accents of cocoa nib. Intriguing and delicious.

Aromas of dark chocolate, plum, black cherry, cedar and tarragon jump from the glass.[/vc_column_text][/vc_column][vc_column css=".vc_custom_1460635878309{padding-top: 0px !important;padding-right: 0px !important;padding-bottom: 0px !important;padding-left: 0px !important;}" offset="vc_col-lg-6 vc_col-md-6 vc_hidden-sm vc_hidden-xs"][vc_single_image image="1090" img_size="full" css=".vc_custom_1469109362921{margin-bottom: 0px !important;}"][/vc_column][/vc_row]

Desired format:

```
<div class="whatever class from visual_Composer">
    <p>Whaterver name</p>
    -------->The rest of the HTML data here
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Either Visual composer is not installed or it's disabled, that's why you are getting raw output of shortcodes

Answer (score 0):

After scratching my head for a little bit, the solution is to use the wordpress do_shortcode.

The answer is

```
<?php
    $desc = $product->get_description();
    echo do_shortcode($desc);
?>
```

With the above I get the data from visual composer to formated HTML, hope this can help other programmers. good night!

Answer (score 0):

Enable it from the Role manager option under the WPBakery (visual composer) settings. Give administrator--> Post Type---> Custom and select the required option to display.